# Python: Match values between two csv files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am parsing through two different csv files and need to match a column between them. Currently, when I run the snippet, it returns no matching values when, in reality, there are matching Addresses between the two csv files. The problem I am having is abbreviations with the addresses field in the OnlineData csv file.  For example:

```
In the Addresses csv                             In the OnlineData csv
  4587 Newton Road                                    4587 Newton Rd
  7854 Food Court                                     7854 Food Ct
```

How can I tell Python to look up ***only*** the numbers ('4587') and the first word ('Newton') in both the csv files when looking for matching values.

```
import csv


Addresses = set()

with open ('Addresses.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        Addresses.add(row[1])

OnlineData = set()

with open ('C:/Users/OnlineData.csv') as g:
    for row in csv.reader(g):
        PermitData.add(row[1])


results = Addresses & OnlineData


print 'There are', len(results), 'matching addresses between the two csv files'

for result in sorted(results):
    print result
```

Comment: Instead of adding the full `row[1]` value, truncate that in each loop first, so that the `Road`, `Rd`, `Court` etc component is dropped before attempting the intersection.

Comment: I am sorry if this might sound absurd but do you mean using append?

Comment: I'll write a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in matching portions of the data, you might as well just load that portion into the `set` and then perform the intersection.

```
import csv

Addresses = set()
with open ('Addresses.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        portion = ' '.join(row[1].split()[:-1])  # Loads "4587 Newton" instead of "4587 Newton Road"
        Addresses.add(portion)

OnlineData = set()
with open ('C:/Users/OnlineData.csv') as g:
    for row in csv.reader(g):
        portion = ' '.join(row[1].split()[:-1])
        OnlineData.add(portion)

results = Addresses & OnlineData

print 'There are', len(results), 'matching addresses between the two csv files'

for result in sorted(results):
    print result
```

The obvious disadvantage is that you lose that bit of information, which you could still retrieve. Another option would be to normalize the input, meaning that you could replace `Rd` with `Road` and `Ct` with `Court` wherever those appear, so as to have always matching info.